# Tuple behaviour in member functions

Tags: c++, function, class, tuples, member

I came across the following conflict of definition and usage of a class member function in my code, with the cpp file as:

```
std::tuple<float, float> SomeClass::SomeFunction(){
     ~~ do something ~~
    return {float1, float2};
}

void SomeClass::AnotherFunction(){
    SomeFunction();
}
```

The function 'SomeFunction' was being called without the tuple it returns being assigned to anything. Fixing the code so that the returned tuple is assigned some to some variables doesn't seem to change the running of my program (it works with or without the tuple being assigned, and the results, which is a numerical computation, is the same either way).

I don't understand why the code can work as above, and I would previously have thought the compilation would fail at this point in my code. Is there some special behaviour of tuples in c++ which I have missed?

Comment: You can ignore the return value of any function in C++, that is unrelated to tuples

Comment: Considering my previous comment the real question is why you thought ignoring the return value is not allowed (or should change the behavior of the code)

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm coming from python (only recently started c++), and the biggest adjustment is that c++ is a more strongly typed language. And because of this I think I have been in the mindset of making sure every single bit of code is typed as strongly as possible. I don't know if the return types of functions is even related to the typing of a language but it seems to occupy a similar place in my thinking about the language.

Comment: "strong typing" and whether function return values are used are not connected. C++ does not enforce that a function's return value has to be used by the caller. Since C++17 functions can be marked to issue compiler warning if a return value is not used, but that requires programmers to mark functions as such: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard